# If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement phone authentication in my app using Firebase.
This user enters the phone number, it is formatted automatically, and when the user finished typing the phone number, a validation function is applied, and after I appeal `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil)`...only if it would work:

```
TextField("Phone number", text: Binding(
    get: {
        phoneNumber
    },
    set: { newValue in
        phoneNumber = newValue
        phoneNumber = formatPhoneNumber(newValue) ?? "+\((countryCodes_PhoneNumber[Locale.current.regionCode ?? ""] ?? ""))"
    }
), onEditingChanged: { editing in
    // Handle editing state changes here
    if editing {
        phoneNumber = "+\(getCountryCode())\(phoneNumber)"
    } else {
        phoneNumber = formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) ?? "+\((countryCodes_PhoneNumber[Locale.current.regionCode ?? ""] ?? ""))"
        if !isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
            alertMessage = "Please verify your phone number"
            alertTitle = "Invalid phone number"
            showAlert = true
        } else {
            
            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { code, err in
                if let error = err {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    alertMessage = "Please try again. \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    alertTitle = "Could not sent verification code"
                    showAlert = true
                } else {
                    verificationSMSCode = code!
                    isVerifyButtonVisible_PhoneNumber = true
                    alertMessage = "Please wait until you receive the code"
                    alertTitle = "Verification code sent to \(phoneNumber)"
                    showAlert = true
                }
            }
     
        }
    }
})
.onChange(of: phoneNumber) { newValue in
    phoneNumber = formatPhoneNumber(newValue) ?? "+\((countryCodes_PhoneNumber[Locale.current.regionCode ?? ""] ?? ""))"
}
.autocapitalization(.none).disableAutocorrection(true).foregroundColor(.white).opacity(1.0).gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
    UIApplication.shared.dismissKeyboard()
}))

.focused($focusedField, equals: .email)
.focused($isFocused)
.padding()
.background(Color.clear)
.keyboardType(.numberPad)

.background(
    Spacer() // Add Spacer to increase tappable area
)
```

When "editing" becomes false I validate the phone number. After I pass this test, I run to the `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil)`, and after that in the error statement case. Here I receive these 2 errors:

```
[Firebase/Auth][I-AUT000015] The UIApplicationDelegate must handle remote notification for phone number authentication to work.
If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.
```

I have tried all the suggestions wrote here for another one who had this issue some time ago, but nothing worked, I have also tried with the help of the Firebase and github documentation, nothing worked.

I am not able to find any solution. If it helps, everytime when a user sends a message to another user, by using the "deviceToken" saved in server of that another user, the notifications WORK, and the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" function in AppDelegate is triggered. HOWEVER, when using `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil)` the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function in AppDelegate is not even triggered.
Here is the AppDelegate and the @main in my App:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import BackgroundTasks
import UIKit
import GoogleUtilities
import Purchases
import FBSDKCoreKit
import Photos
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInAppMessaging
import FirebaseMessaging

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    //@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State var set:Bool = true
    
    init(){
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        Purchases.debugLogsEnabled = true
      
        Purchases.logLevel = .debug
        
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LaunchView()
                .environmentObject(ContentModel())
                .onAppear {
                }
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    print("Received URL: \(url)")
                    Auth.auth().canHandle(url) // <- just for information purposes
                }
            
        }.onChange(of: scenePhase) { scene in
            
            if scene == .background {
                
            }
            else if scene == .inactive {
                
            } else if scene == .active {
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        //Activata da eroarea :Default app has already been configured
        // FirebaseApp.configure()
        //Rezolvare gasita pe stackoverflow
        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
        
        //Setting Up Clous Messaging...
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        //Setting up Notifications...
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.badge, .sound, .alert]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: { _, _ in }
            )
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
            
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        return true
    }
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
      for urlContext in URLContexts {
          let url = urlContext.url
          Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
      }
      // URL not auth related; it should be handled separately.
    }
    
    //For reciving notifications
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        //print("DEICE TOKEN: \(deviceToken)")
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
            // Firebase can handle the notification, so we complete with no data
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
        // Process the notification here since Firebase cannot handle it
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        // Complete with new data indicating that new data was fetched in response to the notification
        completionHandler(.newData)
        
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        
        if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
}

//Cloud Messaging..
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        
        //Store token in Firebase for sending notifications in future
        print(dataDict)
    }
    
    
}

//User Notifications...
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        //Do sth with MSG data
        
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        print(userInfo)
        
        // completionHandler([[ .banner, .badge, .sound]])
        completionHandler([[.badge, .sound, .banner]])
        
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            
            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
            //Print message ID
            if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
                print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
            }
            print(userInfo)
            
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
    
}
```

I have my APNs key set in Firebase, and for any case I also have the certificates created in Apple Developer.
I have Phone Auth enabled.
In Signing and Capabilities I have Background fetch, notifications and procesing enabled, Push Notifications and in Info tab at URL Types my firebase reverse domain.

My messaging notifications inside the app work perfectly, and the users always receive notifications whether they are in background, foreground or with the app running.

But now, personally, I think the problem is that `didReceiveRemoteNotification` does not even trigger, is not executed at all, it is totally ignored. And I think this might be the issue and I have no ideea how to solve it.

Comment: No one answered but the solution which worked for me was to appeal Firebase.configure() in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions rather than in init() in struct TheAppName: App { @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase init(Firebase.configure()) }